# Context Action Bar in Fragments

Tags: android

does anyone have a tutorial to implement a CAB in fragment that uses support library v7 (appcomat_v7)?

I cant find any plus the developer.android tutorial is ambiguous.

Here is my code so far. I am doing a simple test program that as you select items in the list, the context action bar will appear that says stuff like you selected x items and bring up a delete button.

I am trying to do this in a fragment is well so all code posted here is inside a fragment.

**the context bar XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:idk="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_delete"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        idk:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Delete"/>

</menu>
```

This is the implementation of the ActionMode.Callback interface

```
private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback()
{

    // Called when the user selects a contextual menu item
        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(item.getItemId())
            {
            case R.id.menu_delete:
                return true;

            }

            return false;
        }


        //// Called when the action mode is created; startActionMode() was called
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.delete_only, menu);
            return true;
        }

         // Called when the user exits the action mode
        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mActionMode = null;
        }

        //// Called each time the action mode is shown. Always called after onCreateActionMode, but
        // may be called multiple times if the mode is invalidated.
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
};
```

This is the on Item Click Listener for the list view

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(listItemSelections.contains(1) && mActionMode == null)
        {
            mActionMode = getActivity().startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
        }

    }
```

This is the line that gives me the error

```
mActionMode = getActivity().startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
```

It says

```
The method startActionMode(ActionMode.Callback) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments (ActionMode.Callback)
```

Im not sure what to do, I cant find a tutorial that explains the implementation within a fragment and using the support library.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  you are using Action bar library then use this.

```
 ActionBarActivity activity=(ActionBarActivity)getActiivty();
 activity.startSupportActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
```

and if it is simple activity then prefer this one

```
 getActivity().startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
```

Comment: what abotu for toolbar android

Answer (score 1):

If you're using support library, then you should use

```
mActionMode = getActivity().startSupportActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
```

Instead of

```
mActionMode = getActivity().startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
```

Check for more details [Support v7 ActionMode CallBack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/view/ActionMode.Callback.html)